# Where in the system catalog is the function body stored?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I am trying to build a documentation system for my database and I would like to include the source of my functions and triggers.

I managed to find all of the metadata on functions and triggers, but where is the actual body of these functions and triggers stored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the function [`pg_get_functiondef()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) to get the complete function definition:

```
SELECT pg_get_functiondef('my_schema.my_func(int)'::regprocedure)
```

The cast to the [object identifier `regprocedure`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html) is the simplest way to get the `oid` of your function, which you feed to the above function.

[The manual on `pg_catalog.pg_proc`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-proc.html)

> For compiled functions, both built-in and dynamically loaded, `prosrc`
>   contains the function's C-language name (link symbol). For all other
>   currently-known language types, `prosrc` contains the function's source text.

To retrieve the function body only:

```
SELECT prosrc 
FROM   pg_proc
WHERE  oid = 'my_schema.my_func(int)'::regprocedure;
```

Comment: Brilliant. One simple addition: function prototype needs to be schema qualified (at least in my case with schemas not in the search path).

I had gone over the pg_proc catalog table already but was confused by the fact that most columns show data but not the last few, including the prosrc column. Of course I was doing this as a "power user" (CREATEDB, CREATEROLE) when I should have been a superuser... The ACL was not very helpful to me: `{=r/postgres}` and showing some column data but obviously not all.

Answer (score 0):

For such thing I used `pg_dump --schema_only [database]` but now I use my specialized tool to report schema in easy to compare format:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576557-dump-postgresql-db-schema-to-text/

Of course it reads function/procedure bodies/

Answer (score 0):

```
\ef sumall
```

This command fetches and edits the definition of the named function or procedure, in the form of a CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION or CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE command. Editing is done in the same way as for \edit. If you quit the editor without saving, the statement is discarded. If you save and exit the editor, the updated command is executed immediately if you added a semicolon to it. Otherwise it is redisplayed; type semicolon or \g to send it, or \r to cancel.
Link: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PATTERNS

```
\sf+ sumall
```

This command fetches and shows the definition of the named function or procedure, in the form of a CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION or CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE command. The definition is printed to the current query output channel, as set by \o.

In PSQL, now you can get the definition of the function, you can also edit it from the above mentioned two PSQL meta command.