# How to get a list of stored procedures using a specific table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, function, plpgsql

In PostgreSQL (9.3) is there a simple way to get a list of the stored procedures that use a specific table?

I'm changing several tables and need to fix the stored procedures that use them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559008/list-stored-functions-using-a-table-in-postgresql

Comment: @Greg Problem is, I need only the procedures using a specific table--not a list of all the procedures in the database ?? Do I need to read each procedure manually?

Comment: didn't know that, sorry..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Functions which have text 'thetable' in their body.**

The query returns function name, line number and line containg 'thetable':

```
select *
from (
    select proname, row_number() over (partition by proname) as line, textline
    from (
        select proname, unnest(string_to_array(prosrc, chr(10))) textline
        from pg_proc p
        join pg_namespace n on n.oid = p.pronamespace
        where nspname = 'public'
        and prosrc ilike '%thetable%'
        ) lines
    ) x
    where textline ilike '%thetable%';
```

**Functions which have any argument or return value of type associated with `thetable`.**

For example:

```
create function f2(rec thetable)...
create function f1() returns setof thetable...
```

This query gives name, return type and types of arguments of the functions:

```
with rtype as (
    select reltype 
    from pg_class
    where relname = 'thetable')
select distinct on (proname) proname, prorettype, proargtypes
from pg_proc p
join pg_namespace n on n.oid = p.pronamespace
cross join rtype
where nspname = 'public'
and (
    prorettype = reltype 
    or reltype::text = any(string_to_array(proargtypes::text, ' ')))
```

Of course, you can merge the queries into one. I am using them for different purposes.

Comment: @kiln Thank you greatly sir...You just saved me hours :)

Answer (score 3):

This task is not simple, because PostgreSQL has not any evidence about dependencies between functions and tables. What I know, there are not any public tool, that does it. One did Skype, but I am not sure if this tool was released outside Skype. If you know C, then you can modify [plpgsql_check](https://github.com/okbob/plpgsql_check/), where this information is available, but it is not used.

There is poor solution - you can try to search specific string in source codes.

```
postgres=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo()
RETURNS int AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT a FROM t1);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION

postgres=# SELECT oid::regprocedure FROM pg_proc WHERE prosrc ~ '\mt1\M';
┌───────┐
│  oid  │
╞═══════╡
│ foo() │
└───────┘
(1 row)
```

`\m \M` are  Regular Expression Constraint see [related docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-matching.html).

Comment: So I'm guessing a text dump to a file followed by a manual search on table name ??

Comment: And to search the complete function definition including the header (where the table name could pop up as type name) use `pg_get_functiondef()` Details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22191178/939860 (When used as row type in the header, there is a dependency on the type in the system, though.)

Comment: @AlanWayne, no - you can search in table, where source code is stored.