# PostgreSQL 9.5: Describe function in UNIX terminal

Tags: postgresql, unix

I am using the following command to describe the function in Unix.

`\df+ functionName`

Problem: Unable to read the description of the function.

Is there any other method to look the function with the proper indentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where in the system catalog is the function body stored?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190772/where-in-the-system-catalog-is-the-function-body-stored)

Comment: Try `\sf functionName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start `psql` with key `-E` (`psql -E`) and run your `\df+ functionName`, you will see, that it takes definition from `pg_catalog.pg_proc`, so you can just query it like `select prosrc from pg_proc where proname = 'functionName';'`

Same for `\sf functionName` - it's is a wrap up for `pg_catalog.pg_get_functiondef`.

Lastly if you do it your way, with `\df+`, just run `\x` before it and `Source code` will look much better.

**Anyway in ALL those case indentation is saved:**

```
b=# create function p() returns text
b-# as
b-# $$
b$# begin
b$#   --tab
b$#   --two spaces
b$#    --three spaces
b$#   return 't';
b$# end;
b$# $$ language plpgsql
b-# ;
CREATE FUNCTION
b=# \x
Expanded display is on.
b=# \df+ p
List of functions
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------+------------------
Schema              | public
Name                | p
Result data type    | text
Argument data types |
Type                | normal
Security            | invoker
Volatility          | volatile
Owner               | postgres
Language            | plpgsql
Source code         |                  +
                    | begin            +
                    |   --tab          +
                    |   --two spaces   +
                    |    --three spaces+
                    |   return 't';    +
                    | end;             +
                    |
Description         |

b=# \sf p
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.p()
 RETURNS text
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin
  --tab
  --two spaces
   --three spaces
  return 't';
end;
$function$
```